# Can react native used to build my bluetooth apps?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'v project with my lecture to build android/ios app that control motor through blutooth HC05 with openCM microcontroller.

The app should have capability to get and send data to the motor and save data locally

Can it be done using react native?
I have know a bit of html, css, and JavaScript. I just see react native as a good alternative to build my app than i build it with java or obj c since i dont know both. So before i learn deeper about react n I want to know, can i use react native for my project.

[Bluetooth HC05](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/Serial_Port_Bluetooth_Module_(Master/Slave)_:_HC-05)

Comment: Sure, but the BT code will still be native. Your UI work might be easier, but if it's just a simple motor controller, there wouldn't be much to the UI anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's mean the bt code still need java? i'm sorry I new in app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native is probably not a good fit for you if your main goal is to avoid writing native code. You will still have to learn the different Bluetooth APIs and their quirks in addition to writing native modules to expose them to JavaScript.

Comment: whats the most fit way to develop my app then? any suggestion

Comment: Learn how to make an Android app with Java or an iOS app with Objective-C. Then learn the other platform, finally learn React Native.